# What do I do with all my old block erupters?

Tags: mining-profitability, altcoin, asic

I'm making like nothing off these guys and am looking to use them for something else.  I guess these ASICs are designed for SHA-256 hash function based cryptocurrencies.

Try to mine Terracoin?

cryptocurrency list:
http://dustcoin.com/

Answer (score 4):

I use mine in "lottery mode" as I call it.

They don't really consume too much energy, so I just let them solo mine. Big chance will turn out to be nothing, but with some luck they will ever find a block and cash in 25 BTC.

How low the chance may be, it's still a lot higher than winning the ordinary lottery and way cooler :)

**EDIT**: A quick calculation of your odds.

The current (2014/01/24 23:07) chance of a hash to be a winning hash is [0.0000000000000000001061272725905534506860017351925762341](https://blockexplorer.com/q/probability). Then the odds of winning each day are for one block erupter USB of 330MH/s

`0.0000000000000000001061272725905534506860017351925762341 * 330*10^6 * 60*60*24 = 1 / 330480.1`

So one chance in 330,480 each day or one chance in 905 a year (of course, changing difficulty has to be taken into account).

Let's take the Powerball lottery as a reference as Earlz mentions, it has odds of one in 648,975.96 to win $10,000 one in 5,153,632.65 to win $1,000,000.

So, every day you have double the chance to win 25 BTC than you have to win $10k, which is less and costs you probably a dollar or two to enter.

Comment: I computed the probability on something like this once and it is ridiculously low. I used CPU mining as the bitcoin lotto though. Basically, you have a significantly better chance at winning the powerball lottery than mining a single block with less than a few ghash/s

Comment: Well, I believe you don't. I'll update the anwer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately these small asics will eventually be useless unless you want to keep one or two around on the off-chance that you will want to start your own crypto-currency.

However, if you have a pile of 10-20 of them setting around, you could use them as an opportunity to teach people about Bitcoins and how the system operates.

Handing out erupters that you no longer need could be a good way to pique the interest of people who have heard of bitcoin, but have never taken a good look at it.

Other than educational purposes, or seeding new cryptos, I see no *long-term* use for these low hash power ASICs.

Comment: This is good for really getting to know the bitcoin ecosystem, to experience all aspects. They could be passed from newbie to newbie. Maybe for a small fee :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's piles of different coins to mine.  Figure out which one is most profitable to mine: http://www.coinwarz.com

Answer (score 0):

Sell them to someone who wants the experience of mining but doesn't have much of a budget for the hardware.   These are easy to package up and cheap to ship so this is a valid and worthy endeavor.

Answer (score 0):

**You really should start to mine new alt-coin !!!**

Look at my experience. I've mine ppcoin in merge pool for long period in 2012. I've got around 100k ppcoins. And I've sold it for month after mining. Not a big deal, 1-2 BTC for that time.

Now look at the price of ppcoin: 0.005 BTC, I may get 500 BTC today.

There are 100 alt-coins with the same algo `sha256`.

Another example, from current state: There was price 1 Satoshi 0.0000 0001 for the MOON coin ( scrypt ). It has been added to cryptsy, and now its price is 28 Satoshi. You can buy alt-coin before it will be added to cryptsy and in 100% get profit. In MOON scenario it is 2800 %. It is rocket!

You better take your hands and start to lurking for new potential good alt-coins with `sha256` algo.

E.g. You can't get luck in solo with current `sha256` alt-coins, check the pools, there is already great amount of asics. 99% of `sha256` coins very rapidly come to the market. Because it is very easy to add similar coin to one bin.

- github.com/zetacoin/zetacoin.git
- github.com/bryan-mills/bytecoin.git
- github.com/terracoin/terracoin.git
- github.com/freicoin/freicoin/
- github.com/asiccoin/asiccoin.git
- github.com/Nameshar/Noirbits.git
- github.com/tigercoin/tigercoin.git
- github.com/Unthinkingbit/groupcoin
- github.com/r3wt/OSC
- github.com/joulecoin/joulecoin.git
- github.com/maxxine/Tekcoin
- github.com/thegreatoldone/Unobtanium.git
- github.com/emarkproject/DEM.git
- github.com/jmsanto123/NaanaYaM.git
- github.com/chronokings/huntercoin
- github.com/snowcoin/snowcoin
- github.com/Sphere2013/GlobeCrypto
- github.com/NKAKoin/IncaKoin
- github.com/chicoin/chicoin

Every this coin you might start to mine with your block erupter.

But! Better, start to lurking for newest one, that have great Idea in the ground:

- Fast block ( e.g. 30 seconds )
- Dynamical difficulty ( unkillable alt-coins )
- Cool name ( e.g. MOON, see like it flew )
- Not yet added to the crypty ( ! ! ! ) ( it is optional )

Look at this super new alt-coin: [Titcoin [TIT]](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=423523.msg4608890#msg4608890)

When you can hold your portfolio for the long period, e.g. half of year, you might meet the same situation that I observe with ppcoin, now. ( 500 BTC ~ half of million USD, just for merge mining. I didn't aim to this alt-coin ever, just mine this alt-coin by the way and sell, and lose this game... )